# Is there any file i can use to be my game database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a simple game in html5 canvas. i run it using javascript . ANd i want it to be a multiplayer game. but first i need to have a database where i can put the x and y position of an object that will run in every 30 milliseconds(it is the keyframes of my game animation.) . i need to save it in a file or database so other players can see the update of x and y position of other players...i hope you get my point...

now i am asking what database or file should i use to do this data position updating . that can be able to update that fast

Comment: if you want my opinion you've asked the wrong question, because questions that require opinion based answers are off topic :p

Comment: what do you mean? should i rephrase my title or question?

Comment: @Darence30 the problem is that there are many databases to choose from; hence the answer will be an opinion (preference about database).

Comment: @Darence30 a more technical, less opinionated question would be how to propagate these positions efficiently, how to deal with large numbers of players or quick update rates, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a scenario like this, you will probably get more mileage if you cache locations in memory locally, but then periodically "sync" them with the database. This will require ways to resolve conflicts in position (e.g. if the position you predict / have on the client-side JavaScript deviates from the actual position as reported by the database) but will allow you to be more efficient (e.g. updating at a faster rate when players are nearer to your player and less frequently when they are far away, for example). It will also allow you to animate your player's movements more steadily without jank in the event that a particular database request falls outside of your frame rate requirements.

As for the database, itself, there are a lot of databases to choose from. However, if you don't want to write the server-side code to provide an API for interacting with your database, then you may be interested in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), which provides direct access from client-side JavaScript (without the need to create your own server / API layer on top of the database). Of course you can also use any other database -- Google Cloud Datastore, Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Cassandra, MongoDB -- and write an appropriate API server layer in the language of your choice (which could also be JavaScript) to provide access to the underlying data, as a valid option as well (and, in fact, that might make more sense if you already have or plan to have a frontend webserver).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer sir. i will try to study the firebase link you said. Im just new in creating a game, lol. This will be a great help for me..